# practicas de powershell

Tags: script, powershell, shell-script

Hola gente me mandaron hacer estos dos ejercicios de shell pero no tengo ni idea, aunque estoy en ello dejo esto por aqui haber si alguien me puede ayudar.

1. Realizar un script que se ejecute al cerrar la sesión del usuario actual y haga
   una copia de su carpeta documentos en otro directorio llamado copias con el
   nombre usuario_dd_mm_yyyy, donde la fecha debe ser la del día en el que se
   hace el backup.
2. Realizar un script que se ejecute al iniciar sesión y que elimine todos los
   elementos del directorio Descargas del usuario.

lo que llevo de codigo es esto que ni si quiera se si esta bien...

```
$sourcePath="C:StartFolder"
$destPath="C:DestFolder"

Get-ChildItem $sourcePath -Recurse -Include '*.foo', '*.bar' | Foreach-Object `
    {
        $destDir = Split-Path ($_.FullName -Replace [regex]::Escape($sourcePath), $destPath)
        if (!(Test-Path $destDir))
        {
            New-Item -ItemType directory $destDir | Out-Null
        }
        $today = (Get-Date -Format yyyy-MM-dd)
        copy-item .\documents\ -destination $destDir.documentos\my-backup-$(Get-Date -format "nombre_yyyy_MM_dd")
    }
   
Remove-Item -recurse C:\Descargas #eliminar directorio
```